# BGE Parenting loop

Tags: game-engine

I have a simple game so far. The game is not made with realistic characters, but "blocky" ones, like Blockland.

[image: The game is blocky]

I have several objects: collision-bound object and body (torso, arms, legs, head). Everything is set to *No Collision* except the bound object. The bound object have <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> movements, and the body has rotation, which comes from the head (I used `ml.inherit` in the mousemove event).

[image: Lf is left leg, rf is right leg, but here is the basic world with the parents and the children]

If I make the **bound object parented to the body** (the head is always the parent on the body), then when the bound object move, the **body won't move**.

On the other hand, if I make the body parented to the bound object, the bound object will not rotate which messes up the movement (I used local coordinates).

How can I make the bound object rotate and the body to move with it?

Comment: Hum, it's hard to figure out what you're talking about, please add an image or attach an example .blend... thx

Comment: I've been stuck here for an hour, and I don't want to give up

Comment: @TheBasicTroublemaker: Showing the logic brick setup for all relevant objects would help. These objects' relationship is clear enough from your explanation (except that the head is *not* the parent), but the logic controlling them is not.

Comment: @Adhi,: So you want me to attach a photo of the logic of the head, and the collision bounds. The body is just inherited rotation from the head. All the bounds has is just WSAD and [SPACE] controls. The head just has the mouselook, property hooks, and that's it.

Comment: @Adhi: You also said "except the head is not the parent," if it was the parent, then the body, arms, feet, and the collision bounds would rotate up and down with the mouselook.

Comment: @TheBasicTroublemaker: That comment was for the sentence "the head is always the parent on the body".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the character to move, and the head to rotate with mouse-movement?

Set up you <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys for the body, parent everything to that, then set up a *Mouse Movement* sensor, connected to a *Python* controller to the head. A link to the *Python* script is below:

http://riyuzakisan.weebly.com/mousemove-script.html

Comment: I would have just posted the code i used, but it's super long and has copyright issues. If you can't find the script, ask me and i'll just send you my .txt file